# Error handling with gulp-ruby-sass 1.0.0-alpha, gulp-notify, and browser-sync

Tags: error-handling, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-notify

I've been using `gulp-ruby-sass@1.0.0-alpha' because < 1.0 doesn't play well with Sass >= 3.4
According to the documentation:

> gulp-ruby-sass throws errors like a gulp plugin, but streams the erroring files so you can see the errors in your browser.

I use `gulp-notify` to handle errors with this code that gives me a popup notification that lets me know that something went wrong.

```
.on('error', notify.onError({
    title: 'Error!',
    message: '<%= error.message %>',
    sound: 'Beep'
}))
```

This works as-is for my other tasks (in my 'scripts' task I need to specify the `gulp-jshint` fail reporter). But in my 'styles' task the error message is being streamed to the console and the browser but not to a popup notification.

It's workable as is, but when using browser-sync for css style injection, the error message can be missed. Sometimes I'm not working at the top of the document where it renders the error message.

Ideally, I would like to receive a notification that can prompt me to check for errors. Does anyone know why I can't create a message with gulp-notify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to wrap `notify.onError` in an anonymous function and append `this.emit('end')`:

```
.on('error', function(err) {
    notify.onError({
        title: 'Error!',
        message: '<%= error.message %>',
        sound: 'Beep'
    })(err);
    this.emit('end');
})
```